# Google "Appearance" settings is not shown

Tags: google-search

I just realized that Google now allows dark mode. After googling for a while, I read that on Windows 10 if you have dark mode enabled, it will ask to switch or apply the dark theme by default. If not, you, theoretically you can enable it from Search Settings / Appearance.

But I still see the light theme and the "Appearance" option is not shown for me:

[image]

I have tried with a different account, with the same browser on the same PC and the "Appearance" menu is, indeed, shown. I have Windows 10 with dark mode enabled at a OS level.

How could I activate this option on Google Search settings for my other account?

Comment: Is this current/affected account a Google Workspace account that is managed by a domain admin?

Comment: It's a personal account. I've tried different browsers, just to discard any settings form it.

Comment: Ah, then sorry, I'm out of ideas :)

Comment: @OnenOnlyWalter  It's OK. I think that it may have to do with the fact that I have all "ads personalizations" and tracking options disabled. Probably a sort of punishment from Google?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google has announced already that it is experimenting with the Dark Background setting, which is already being randomly displayed in the Settings>Appearance menu on the Google search engine.
Not necessarily only Chrome! Just the Google search engine can be used, whether in FireFox, Internet Explorer, etc.

The "Appearance" menu choice appears randomly below or above Languages.

After selecting "Appearance" you can select "Dark Mode".

This testing has been going on for many months during 2021. Sometimes it "Appearance" will appear as a menu choice next to Languages 3 or 4 times after opening the Google Browser. Then, it will not appear for days or opening Google Browser 100 times. Don't hold your breath waiting for it to become a regular part of the Settings.

Comment: Seems odd from Google not to have consistency for the rollout of this feature, and moreover, to be account based. I've tried refreshing the page, clearing cookies and login several times, still the same. Anyway, I'll mark this as accepted soon if there is no more activity on this.

Answer (score 3):

I'd like to chime in here and report that dark theme only seems to work as an option when you are not signed in to Google.  Go to the following url:

https://www.google.com/preferences?hl=en&fg=1#appearance

You should see this:

[image: Google hidden dark theme option]

So far I cannot get this option to show up while signed in to Google on a Windows 8 machine, maybe it is different if someone is on Windows 10?  Hopefully we can get more information about this soon!

Comment: You are right, I only saw the invitation to use dark mode on an incognito window, while I was not signed in. I must add that I use linux, so I don't think the OS is relevant.

Answer (score -1):

I read somewhere that there is a hierarchy ( specificity ) for CSS programming of webpage styles/ appearance. Why does Google override my dark themed OS and dark themed FireFox browser ? Alternatively https://github.com/ankit/stylebot lets you modify the webpage appearance after it's loaded for Chrome, FF and Edge. Reference - https://mediatemple.net/blog/design-creative/bend-websites-css-will-stylish-stylebot/

Comment: This is not an issue about overriding theme, CSS has *nothing* to do with the system theme. Each web page may have its own style/theme that set various foreground and background colors and those may also have to match with images and icons being displayed. The proper way of getting dark mode if by specifying both themes in CSS and using the `prefers-color-scheme` @media feature to let the browser select the correct theme, and this requires web pages to use it. Other hacks works on any page by altering the appearance of the page, and since it's done dynamically the end result may vary.